# How is Karate's Main Class Invoked via IDE(IntellliJ/Eclipse)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, karate

I have started using Karate and found it pleasing to use. As I am exploring, I am curious to know many things about it.

One of them being this:

So, I understand (like Cucumber) there are two ways to run:

1.) Using build tool(say Maven) where it's surefire plugin will look for a runner file (with the prescribed *Test.java naming conventions) and this file would be annotated with (Karate.class). And the execution is transferred to Karate.

2.) IDE which creates Run Configurations (which is basically issuing java command with required classpath and invoking cucumber.api.cli.Main with required parameters related to glue, feature file/scenario line, tags etc. )

But a simple search on IntelliJ shows that there are two .class files on classpath with name - cucumber.api.cli.Main. One from cucumber jar file and the other from Karate.

My question is how is java able to figure out that it has to invoke the one from Karate and not the one from cucumber.

[image]

When I open Run configurations and open an option to choose Main class, it shows me just one when I search for it, as if it knows to ignore the cucumber one. So, even IntelliJ somehow knows this.
[image]

Comment: If there are multiple classes with the same FQN in the classpath, Java picks up the one from the dependency that comes first. So it would depend on the classpath order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm responsible for this hack and not sure of the details, but it seems to work.

I think the simple rule is that the Java class-loader has a sequence / hierarchy - and the classes directly on the classpath are given preference, and any classes within a JAR file are given a lower preference. That's all.

And when both come from a JAR file, the (Maven) dependency order matters.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. And that too from the 'Creator' himself. 
If you see my first image, both the .class files do come from jar and these do jars are what is listed in -cp argument (of java command) when I run it via IDE. Yes, karate jar is listed before cucumber. And I think this where it intercepts.
Same could be the reason as to why IntelliJ is not showing main class of cucumber when I search it. Of course if i just search 'main' it gets listed.
Can I ask one more thing? How is 'glue' figured out. I can see in the command line that it has populated glue as 'com.intuit.karate'

Comment: @pragun I really don't know how IntelliJ does it ! but my guess is if it scans and finds only one, it assumes that that is "the one". in Eclipse for e.g. I think the user has to enter the package name manually